# Пробросить fastcgi_params в консольный скрипт

Tags: php, yii2, nginx, php7, php-fpm

Моя конфигурация nginx имеет следующий вид

```
location ~* \.(php)$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

`fastcgi_params` имеет переменную `DB_PASSWORD`.
И я могу получить значение этой переменной, запустив php-скрипт в браузере через `$_SERVER['DB_PASSWORD']`, но если я запускаю консольный скрипт, например

```
./yii migrate/up
```

То этих переменных `$_SERVER` уже не содержит. Как их туда пробросить?
Использую `php-fpm`

Answer (score 2):

Пробросить fastcgi_params в консольный скрипт невозможно.

FastCGI - интерфейс между веб-сервером и PHP. Путь такой: переменная из конфига => протокол FastCGI => PHP интерпретатор разбирает запрос по протоколу (см также [variables_order](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order)) => глобальная переменная в вашем PHP-скрипте.

Консольный скрипт запускает интерпретатор по CLI SAPI (`php cli`). FastCGI тут не используется, так как запуск из командной строки, и веб-сервер не принимает ни какого участия. Также `php cli` имеет собственный `php.ini` файл, поэтому конфигурация у него отдельная. Узнать ее можно так: `php --ini`

Если вам нужны переменные в php-cli - используйте окружение.

### 1 способ - через командную строку (мой выбор)

```
DB_PASSWORD=password php {ваш скрипт}.php
```

### 2 способ - экспорт в окружение

```
export DB_PASSWORD=password
php {ваш скрипт}.php
```

### 3 способ - выставить на уровне всей ОС (не рекомендуется)

Нужно отредактировать `/etc/environment`, изменения будут видны после перезапуска службы (для пользователя - перелогиниться). Для передачи пароля этот способ плохой по безопасности: виден всем.

### 4 способ - для Docker

Если используется Docker, в `Dockerfile` возможно записать `ENV DB_PASSWORD=password`, или передать из командной строки при старте:

```
docker run ... -e DB_PASSWORD=password ...
```

## Доступ в PHP

Внутри скрипта будет доступно:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['DB_PASSWORD']); 
var_dump(getenv('DB_PASSWORD'));
```

PS. Узнать какой SAPI используется можно через [php_sapi_name()](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.php-sapi-name.php).